# Model function returns empty one column

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

### Main photo

I created update form that send to controller id and everything is working good. However, main photo how I checked returns the data which was firstly added. For example event_id = 2 does not have main picture and event_id = 4 has main_photo (eg:test) but it gets event_id = 2 empty value. I spend a lot of time however cannot find the solution.

### Modell

```
public function get_list_for_edit($event_id){
    return
    $this->db->select('*')
              ->select('pn.title as push_title, e.title as event_title', false) 
              ->from('events e')
              ->join('events_locations el','el.event_id =' . $event_id,'left')
              ->join('push_notifications pn',
                      'pn.type_id ='. $event_id,'left')

              ->get('events')
              ->row_object();
}
```

### Array 1 event_id = 2

```
  stdClass Object
   (
[event_id] => 2
[title] => test1 -pushnotificationtitle
[description] => <p>Test1 -description</p>
[main_photo] => 
[start] => 2017-03-12 08:00:00
[end] => 2017-03-15 06:00:00
[phone] => 946871783
[email] => abdurasulov.ravshan@gmail.com
[keywords] => test1 -keywords
[created_at] => 2017-03-12 20:29:09
[status] => active
[deleted] => 0
[event_location_id] => 2
[country_id] => 1
[city_id] => 1
[area_id] => 1
[street] => Tinchlik street
[building_no] => Tinchlik street
[latitude] => 25.218670435768225
[longitude] => 55.29264020500705
[push_notificaion_id] => 2
[type] => event
[type_id] => 2
[datetime] => 2017-03-12 20:29:09
[message] => test1 -pushnotificationmessage
[push_title] => test1 -pushnotificationtitle
[event_title] => Test1
 )
```

### Array 2 event_id = 5

```
stdClass Object
 (
[event_id] => 5
[title] => test4 - notificationtitle
[description] => <p>Test1 -description</p>
[main_photo] => 
[start] => 2017-03-12 08:00:00
[end] => 2017-03-15 06:00:00
[phone] => 946871783
[email] => abdurasulov.ravshan@gmail.com
[keywords] => test1 -keywords
[created_at] => 2017-03-12 20:45:47
[status] => active
[deleted] => 0
[event_location_id] => 5
[country_id] => 1
[city_id] => 1
[area_id] => 1
[street] => Tinchlik street
[building_no] => Tinchlik street
[latitude] => 25.197858466144194
[longitude] => 55.244231696706265
[push_notificaion_id] => 5
[type] => 
[type_id] => 5
[datetime] => 2017-03-17 08:00:00
[message] => test4 - notificationtitle
[push_title] => test4 - notificationtitle
[event_title] => Test1
  )
```

Comment: Please can you properly elaborate your issue. Unable to understand your issue.

Comment: I want to get by id however one main photo returns which one added firstly

Comment: I would use a different query for this, that's what I do anyways.
Get all the images-> check if one is main-> if not get another one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you need to get one image but a main image may or may not be available, this is what I do:

Controller:

```
//get your event
$data['event'] = $this->db->get_where('event_table')->row();

$data['event']->main_image = $this->event_model->get_main_image($data['event']);
```

Model:

```
        //get all images
        $images = $this->db->get_where('e_products_main_images', array('main_image_product_id_fk' => $product->product_id))->result();
        $image = null;

        //check if main exists
        foreach ($images as $key => $animage) {
            if ($aniamge->is_main == '1') {
                $image = $aniamge;
            } 
        }

        //if not get the first one
        if ($image == null and isset($images[0])) {
            $image = $images[0];
        }

        //or return null
        if ($image == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return $image->main_image_path;
```